# How can I merge unsorted linked list in java

Tags: java, merge, singly-linked-list

// How can I make this function? I want to merge two unsorted linked list.

```
public static LinkedList mergeUnsortedLists(LinkedList list1, LinkedList list2) {
    LinkedList list3= new LinkedList();
    Node curr_odd = list1.head;
    Node curr_even = list2.head;
    Node prev = null;
    
    while(curr_odd != null){
        prev = curr_odd;
        curr_odd = curr_odd.getNext();
    
    }
    
    prev = curr_even;
    
  return list3;
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static LinkedList mergeUnsortedLists(LinkedList list1, LinkedList list2) { 
    if (lis1.head == null) {
        return list2;
    }

    if (list2.head == null) {
        return list1;
    }

    for (Node crt = list1.head; crt.getNext() != null; crt = crt.getNext());
    
    // Need to link last element in l1 to head element of l2
    crt.setNext(list2.head);
    
    return list1;
}
```